# Dataset with a multivariate time series of circular and linear variables

Tags: data-request, biology, time-series

I am looking for a multivariate time series (at least 2000 times) where there must be a circular variable and a linear one.

For example a time series of wind and wave direction (circular data) and wind speed and wave height (linear data). i do not need this particular dataset, i already have this dataset, i need something different.

A dataset with ecological meaning should be better.

Comment: Are you looking for such a data set that is completely different from wave direction and wind speed/wave height? Perhaps temperature (circular) and something else?

Comment: Yes, i am looking for something else different from wave and wind dataset. I do not understand why you say that temperature is circular.

Comment: my bad, definition of circular variable was off

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'circular data' ... is this just a vector given in polar coordinates?

Comment: Something that can be expressed as an angle, like the wind  or wave direction or a variable whose domain is a circle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics. Another example: if you track the animal movement in a 2 dimensional space, the angle formed by three consecutive observations is an angular(circular variable), that represent the change in direction.

Comment: The domain of a vector (for example a vector of 2 variables)  expressed in polar coordinates is $\mathbb{R}^2$, not a circle. Of course i can use only the angle of the polar coordinates transformation as circular variable, but i want a circular variable that as a "meaning" (as the wind direction).

Comment: You might also want to add "vector field" to your google search.  That is another way of displaying directional data.

Answer (score 1):

There is an area of statistics called functional data analysis.  If you look through the documentation for these procedures (R and matlab) or the books/short courses, you should be able to find a dataset that meets your needs.

- http://faculty.bscb.cornell.edu/~hooker/ShortCourseHandout.pdf
- http://www.psych.mcgill.ca/misc/fda/
- http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fda/index.html
- [http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Data-Analysis-Springer-Statistics/dp/038740080X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1421760835&sr=8-1&keywords=functional+data+analysis&pebp=1421760797440&peasin=038740080X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038740080X)